# What is a name for someone who doesn't want to get their hands dirty, has their nose turned up, or is too good for anyone?

Tags: meaning, word-request

Someone who is too good for someone? Or who doesn't want to get their hands dirty?

Comment: It would be helpful to us if you could give us an example sentence or situation so that we understand more exactly the meaning you want.

Comment: Prig (n), prissy (adj), a Felix Unger (n).  But the "or" in your question makes it hard to answer. Do you want separate terms for these types, or a single term that covers both? If the latter, use _and_ in your question.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few words for that. Posh, stuck-up, snooty, pompous, pretentious (and more) all have similar meanings.

Do you have a specific context you are looking at? It'll be easier to pinpoint a word that way.

Answer (score 1):

["Snob"](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/snob) is a good word for that. The adjective form is "snobby". But like Loocid said, there are many words that could work.

Comment: Ah, I forgot about snob. That would work well too.

Comment: All of the suggestions so far imply that there is something wrong with the subject's behavior.  On the other hand, if no criticism is intended towards the subject, the term "fastidious" would apply. Not getting one's hands dirty, for instance, is a form of good hygiene. Turning up one's nose at others' behavior is not objectionable if the others are behaving disgustingly (cannibalism, pederasty, sadism, etc).